# Howto Save Shared Query in App Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

How do I save a shared query in App Insights?  I can't seem to find any info on this.  Am I missing it?

When I go to save a query, I don't see anything asking me about the location.

[image: save dialog screenshot]

I do see [this user voice item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/15643749-shared-saved-queries) that says it is possible.  And I see Shared Queries in the Query Explorer:

[image: query explorer screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From [this article](https://sarafian.github.io/azure/2019/07/25/kusto-fx-functions-application-insights-logs-analytics.html)**

> What you need is the **Application Insights Component Contributor** and **Application Insights Snapshot Debugger** roles on the applications insights instance as described in the [Resources, roles, and access control in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/resources-roles-access-control) page. With these roles, you can create and edit existing functions as well as shared queries.

**Steps to do this in Azure Portal**

1. Go the Application Insights instance (the same place you run queries will do).
2. Click "Access Control (AIM)" in the left-most nav panel.
3. On the "Grant access to this resource" panel click the "Add role assignments" button.
4. Fill out the form:

   - Role: "Application Insights Component Contributor"
   - Assign access to: "User, group, or service principal"
   - Find your user or search by email address for the last field
   - Save
5. Repeat step 4 but for the "Application Insights Snapshot Debugger" role

**Notes**

- You may need an administrator to add the role if you don't have permissions.
- The form values for who to assign the role may vary depending on how your company manages roles and RBAC.  Ideally all employees needing these permissions would be in a group and the roles would be given to the group.
- It is possible only one of these roles is needed for saving Shared Queries.  The article mentions two permissions, but one may be specifically for creating/editing custom functions.

**Application Insights Access Control Screenshot**

[image: Application Insights Access Control Page]

Answer (score 3):

When you press the save button you should get to choose the destination:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Peter, that's what I would have expected.  I've added a screeshot of what I see.